# firebase C++ sdk on ios firebase::App::Create returns nullptr

Tags: c++, ios, firebase

The below "helpful" messages are logged by the underlying objective-c sdk:

```
ERROR: Unable to configure Firebase services: Neither name nor options can be nil. 
<Notice>: [2017.07.28-02.15.27:187][585] Created Firebase App: 0x0 
<Notice>: [Firebase/Core][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
```

Of course, I am passing the app name and the options to the C++ api (and none of them are nullptr):

```
firebase::AppOptions AppOptions;
const char* app_id = ...
AppOptions.set_app_id(app_id);
const char* project_id = ...
AppOptions.set_project_id(project_id);
const char* api_key = ...
AppOptions.set_api_key(api_key);
const char* gcm_sender_id = ...    
AppOptions.set_messaging_sender_id(gcm_sender_id);
const char* database_url = ...
AppOptions.set_database_url(database_url);
const char* storage_bucket = ...
AppOptions.set_storage_bucket(storage_bucket);
firebase::App* AppPtr = firebase::App::Create(AppOptions, app_id);
Log("Created Firebase App %p", AppPtr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Firebase engineer here,

We currently do not expose all required options in the firebase::AppOptions interface.  The configuration file (plist on iOS / json on Android) specify a number of configuration values that are required by the API but not specified by developers during App initialization.  Therefore - at the moment - we require the config file (plist on iOS) to be included in the application in order to initialize the underlying Obj-C SDK.

I'm sure you've already look at it, but our setup flow is documented here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup

Cheers,
Stewart

Comment: Specifically which options are required in the plist file? The issue is we need to support accessing multiple firebase apps. Can that be done with the current C++ api?

Comment: As an experiment I downloaded and added one of the project's GoogleService-Info.plist files. Now the message "Could not locate configuration file" isn't logged, however the other message still is and firebase::App::Create still returns null.

Comment: Btw since the C++ api is just a wrapper around your already open-source objc sdk, it seems a bit pointless to keep it closed-source. I could easily resolve this problem myself if that wasn't the case.

Comment: The plist is supposed to be opaque, if you copy and paste values from it into your app it's going to break as we evolve the configuration values.  In terms of the failure to create firebase::App we'll need to see the code you're using to create it.  It would be great to see whether you can reproduce with one of our quickstart samples on github first https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-cpp .  w.r.t C++ just being a wrapper, I assure you it's a non-trivial amount of code and build logic.  Migrating to an external build system is small exercise, we're investing elsewhere at the moment.

Comment: Stewart, would you mind answering this question: The issue is we need to support accessing multiple firebase apps. Can that be done with the current C++ api?  And yes the same problem exactly occurs with quickstart by simply adding the above code to the beginning of common_main.cc - I've previously reported that to google support. Sad that stackoverflow is more responsive tbh.

Comment: Ah I see.  We recently discovered a bug in the C++ iOS SDK that wasn't applying custom options.  The fix is released in 4.0.3 https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/cpp-relnotes .